# How to Call Symfony action using shell_exec

Tags: php, symfony1, background-process

I have Problem with symfony i would like to execute the backend process from inside the symfony action like below

```
shell_exec("php http://localhost/esm/symfony/web/index.php/payroll/StartProcess");
```

This command actually not working even im not getting any error or message after excecute this  action

my StartProcess action is like below

```
$query="INSERT INTO test_process (value) VALUES (1)";
       $conn = Doctrine_Manager::getInstance()->connection();
$stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute();
```

Please Help Why this is not working

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create new task with:

```
php symfony generate:task updateincrement:employee
```

Then execute it with:

```
php symfony updateincrement:employee
```